# jquery select dropdown ignores keydown event when it's opened?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, preventdefault, backspace

I'm trying to prevent backspace button to go one page back in every browser. For now I'm using this code:

```
$(document).on("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.which === 8 && !$(e.target).is("input, textarea")) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

It works fine for everything except when a select field dropdown list **is opened**, this event is ignored and a backspace takes me one page back anyway. How can I solve this problem? Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for the info, this is Google Chrome specific since your code works fine in IE and FF.

If you really need this to work you could render a fake dropdown and than set select programmaticly.

You can change the size of dropdown to appear as it was open, something like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/yzr2cmqv/

```
<div clas="select-wrap">
    <div class="fake-select"></div>
    <select class="select">
        <option value="1">one</option>
        <option value="2">two</option>
        <option value="3">three</option>
    </select>
</div>

$(".fake-select").on("click", function () {
    var numOfOpen = $("select.select option").size();
    $(".select").attr("size", numOfOpen).css("overflow", "hidden");
    $(this).hide();
});

$(".select").on("click", function () {
    $(".select").attr("size", 1);
    $(".fake-select").show();
});
```

Other than that I don't think you can do anything since Chrome events are not firing when dropdown is open.

Comment: Looks like it's a bug in Chrome. I have reported it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Cool technique to change `size` though it unfortunately breaks keyboard navigation...

Comment: You could implement additional events on key up/down, to reproduce same logic, somethink like this fidle:

https://jsfiddle.net/yzr2cmqv/15/

Answer (score -2):

Just add the `select` tag to your selector:

```
$(document).on("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.which === 8 && !$(e.target).is("input, textarea, select")) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: You didn't understand my qustion. What you did makes it worse. Default event in select is page back and if I add it where you suggest it, it won't work also with a dropdown closed.

Answer (score -2):

You'll have to check for keydown event on $(select) right now, if you add

```
console.log(e.which)
console.log(e.target)
```

you'll notice that you won't get the keydown event when you click and press your keyboard while the select dropdown is active.

This will make it for your

```
$(document).on("keydown", $('select'), function (e) {
    if (e.which === 8) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: hmm, i noticed that my code only work if the select is active, while it is focused but it needs to be closed. I realized it doesn't work while the select is opened..

Comment: I already tried that. It doesn't help. As I said my code works for select when a dropdown is closed. The problem is when a dropdown is opened. And the same problem is in your suggestion.