# OnChange - Pause function if shift or control key is down

Tags: javascript, jquery

I’m using the following function to populate some combo boxes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getcompany() {
    $.post('filters.php', 
       $('form[name="report1"]').serialize(), 
       function (output) {
       var options = output.split(',');
           $('#M1').html(options[0]).show();
           $('#T1').html(options[1]).show();
           $('#I1').html(options[2]).show();
           $('#C1').html(options[3]).show();
       });
}
</script>
```

This is trigged by an OnChange event and works fine if a user only wants to filter by one item in the combo box. But if the Control or Shift key is used with the intention of selecting multiple items, the options change before selecting the next item.  So, what I need is a way to detect if either of those keys are down, pause the function, then resume it after the key is released.

Comment: You could also add a delay to your function to allow the user to select multiple options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After another day trying things, I came up with this. Also added the shift key.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Set default variable to no
downkey = "No";
//Set variable to yes if key(s) are down
$(document).keydown(function(down){
if(down.keyCode == 16 || down.keyCode == 17) {
downkey = "Yes";
}
});
//Return variable to no and call the function when the key(s) are released
$(document).keyup(function(up){
if(up.keyCode == 16 || up.keyCode == 17) {
downkey = "No";
getcompany(); 
}
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function getcompany() {
if(downkey == "No"){//Checks the downkey variable to see if it is currently set to Yes or No
    $.post('filters.php', 
       $('form[name="report1"]').serialize(), 
        function (output) {
        var options = output.split(',');
            $('#M1').html(options[0]).show();
            $('#T1').html(options[1]).show();
            $('#I1').html(options[2]).show();
            $('#C1').html(options[3]).show();
       });
}
}

</script>
```

Comment: When the dropdown list is open, the keydown listener no longer gets called in Chrome. You can fix with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31155411/jquery-select-dropdown-ignores-keydown-event-when-its-opened

Answer (score -2):

I haven't tested this yet, but you can determine if the control key is pressed using the event object. `e.ctrlKey`

```
button.onclick = function (e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey) {
       //  do nothing
    }else {
       getCompany();
    }
}
```

The same goes for the shift key `e.shiftKey`

```
button.onclick = function (e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey || e.shiftKey) {
       //  do nothing
    }else {
       getCompany();
    }
}
```

Comment: You will likely need a `keyup` listener as well to retrigger the function only if it was blocked earlier

Comment: The onchange event is not a mouse event as such does not have crtlKey or shiftKey.