# Capture keypress event when a select is opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select which is rendered from an asp:DropDownList in a html page which I'm **not** allowed to change. What I'm trying to achieve is to capture the keypress event and reorder the options inside the select depending on the keypress. For example: If the user press A and then B it should order after AB. 
The missing part to achieve this reorder function is to capture the keypress when the select is opened. 

But I can't get it..

Could anyone show me the light on this?
I've basically uses this example:

```js
$(document).on('keypress', function(e){    
  var code = e.keyCode || e.which
  $('#myTextInput').val('');
  $('#myTextInput').val(code);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelectDropDown">
  <option>select 1</option>
  <option>select 2</option>
  <option>select 3</option>
  <option>select 4</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="myTextInput" />
```

Any ideas on how to capture the keypress event when the select is opened?

*Note: I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31155411/jquery-select-dropdown-ignores-keydown-event-when-its-opened) answer but It changes the html which is not what I'm looking for.*

Comment: Why you need this? If this is for autocomplete, you should use plain text input with custom popup..

Comment: May be select is handing the keypress and not propagating it? Can you try listening to keypress event on #mySelectDropDown?

Comment: I've found the only key that opens a select is the space bar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery select dropdown ignores keydown event when it's opened?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31155411/jquery-select-dropdown-ignores-keydown-event-when-its-opened)

Comment: @Hardy The select is rendered from a asp:DropDownList which Im not allowed to change. My idea was to get the value in javascript and reorder the values in client..But I can't get the keypress when its opened.

Comment: @MarcusH why don't you get it on focus or just shuffle the order on load - I take it they are not dynamically loaded so you would only need to change the order once